# How to use multiple queries in one php function

Tags: php, mysql, sql, function

Hi all i was just wondering how I would get a php function to run two sql queries my function at the moment is the code below the connection to the database is at the top of the page so I don't need to right the connection every time my full page code is :

```
<?php
class SelectList
{
    protected $conn;

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->DbConnect();
        }

        protected function DbConnect()
        {
            include "db_config.php";
            $this->conn = mysql_connect($host,$user,$password) OR die("Unable to connect to the database");
            mysql_select_db($db,$this->conn) OR die("can not select the database $db");
            return TRUE;
        }


        public function ShowCategory()
        {
            $sql = "SELECT subject.subject_id,subject.description,COUNT(media.subject_id) as media_count\n"
                 . "from subject LEFT OUTER JOIN media ON subject.subject_id = media.subject_id \n"
                 . "WHERE verified = 1\n"
                 . "GROUP BY subject.subject_id,subject.description ORDER BY subject.description ";
            $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn);
            $category = '<option value="%">Subject</option>';
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
            {
                $category .= '<option value="' . $row['subject_id'] . '">' . $row['description']. '...('.$row['media_count'].')</option>';
            }
            return $category;
        }

        public function ShowType()
        {
           $sql =  "SELECT section.section_id,section.description,section.subject_id,COUNT(media.section_id) as media_count
                    FROM section LEFT OUTER JOIN media ON section.section_id = media.section_id 
                    AND section.subject_id = media.subject_id
                    WHERE section.subject_id={$_POST['id']} AND verified = 1
                    GROUP BY section.section_id,section.description";
            $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn);
            $type = '<option value="%">choose...';
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
            {
                $type .= '<option value="' . $row['section_id'] . '">' . $row['description']. '...('.$row['media_count'].') </option>';
            }
            return $type;
        }

         public function ShowPrinciple()
        {
            $sql = "SELECT principle.principle_id,principle.description,principle.section_id,COUNT(media.principle_id) as media_count
                    FROM principle 
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN media ON principle.principle_id = media.principle_id 
                    AND principle.section_id = media.section_id 
                    WHERE principle.section_id={$_POST['id']} AND verified = 1
                    GROUP BY principle.principle_id,principle.description";
            $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn);
            $principle = '<option value="%">choose...</option>';
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
            {
                $principle .= '<option value="' . $row['principle_id'] . '">' . $row['description'].  '...('.$row['media_count'].') </option>';
            }
            return $principle;
        }

        public function GetResults()
        { 
        //$vars = $_POST["comboboxselections"]; // this gets comboboxselections from index.php

            list($subjectID, $sectionID, $principleID) = explode('#', $_POST["comboboxselections"]);

           $box = ""; // placeholder for the html results to be returned to 
           $sql = "SELECT media_id,title,blurb 
                    FROM media 
                    WHERE subject_id = $subjectID AND section_id = $sectionID AND principle_id= $principleID AND verified = 1"; // sql query 


           $hasprintedrecords = false; // capture records if there are no records printed to screen 
           $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn); // connection to database and also getting the results from query
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) // the loop while there are results within the array run the function
            {
                $hasprintedrecords = true;// if there are records this equals true if not equals false 
                $box .= '

                <div style="margin-top:5px;height:120px;padding:0px;"id="Video">

                <div style="width:185px;height:105px;float:left;" id="VideoImage">
                <img style="width:185px;"class="partimg1" src="images/thumbnails/'.$row['media_id'].'.png" />
                </div>

                <div style="float:right;padding-left:5px;width:72%;font-size:15px;padding-top:0px;font:verdana,sans-serif;" id="text">
                <div style="color:#0099CC;font-weight:bold;" id="Title">'.$row['title'].'</div>
                <a style="color:#000000;text-decoration:none;padding:0px;margin:0px;font-size:12px;" href="http://www.thomasdudley.co.uk/" target="_blank">By Thomas Dudley</a> 
                <div style="font-size:13.4px;"id="Blurb">'.$row['blurb'].'</div>
                <div  id="Downloads">
                <a href="http://thor/classroom/Downloads/'.$row['media_id'].''.$row['title'].'.exe" target="_blank">
                <img style="width:100px; margin-left:-10px;margin-top:10px;" src="images/download.jpg">   
                </a>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>'; // if results are available then display to screen 
            }
            if ( $hasprintedrecords == false) // if there are no results then function below is run  
            { 
            $box .='<div id=\"video\" style=\" border-style:solid; border-color:#000000; border-width:1px;\"> <div style="border-style:dashed; border-color:#f90;" id="text"> no media found for this selection.</div></div>'; // returns html message to screen 
            }
            return $box; // returns results to the screen
        }

        public function ShowJobRole() { 

        $sql = "SELECT jobrole_id,description
        FROM jobrole ";
            $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn);
            $jobrole = '<option value="%">Job role</option>';
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
            {
                $jobrole .= '<option value="' . $row['jobrole_id'] . '">' . $row['description'] . '...('.$row['media_count'].'</option>';
            }
            return $jobrole;
        } 

        public function ShowCareer() { 

        $sql = "SELECT career_id,description FROM career WHERE jobrole_id={$_POST['id']}";
        $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn);
        $career = '<option value="%">Career</option>';
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
        {
            $career .= '<option value="' . $row['career_id'] . '">' . $row['description'] . '</option>';
        }
        return $career;
    } 
        public function get_job () { 

            //$vars1 = $_POST["comboboxselections1"]; // this gets comboboxselections from index.php

            list($jobroleID, $careerID) = explode('#', $_POST["comboboxselections1"]);

            $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn);

            $box = ""; // placeholder for the html results to be returned to 
            $sql = "SELECT title,blurb,m.media_id
                    FROM media_career_crossref mcc
                            INNER JOIN media m ON m.media_id = mcc.media_id 
                    WHERE mcc.jobrole_id = $jobroleID AND mcc.career_id = $careerID";


            $hasprintedrecords = false; // capture records if there are no records printed to screen 

            $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn); // connection to database and also getting the results from query
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) // the loop while there are results within the array run the function
            {
                $hasprintedrecords = true;// if there are records this equals true if not equals false 
             $box .= '
            <div style="margin-top:5px;height:120px;padding:0px;"id="Video">

                <div style="width:185px;height:105px;float:left;" id="VideoImage">
                <img style="width:185px;"class="partimg1" src="images/thumbnails/'.$row['media_id'].'.png" />
                </div>

                    <div style="float:right;padding-left:5px;width:72%;font-size:15px;padding-top:0px;font:verdana,sans-serif;" id="text">
                <div style="color:#0099CC;font-weight:bold;" id="Title">'.$row['title'].'</div>
                <a style="color:#000000;text-decoration:none;padding:0px;margin:0px;font-size:12px;" href="http://www.thomasdudley.co.uk/" target="_blank">By Thomas Dudley</a> 
                <div style="font-size:13.4px;"id="Blurb">'.$row['blurb'].'</div>
                <div  id="Downloads">
                <a style="width:100px; margin-left:-10px;margin-top:10px;" href="http://thor/classroom/Downloads/'.$row['media_id'].''.$row['title'].'.exe" target="_blank">
                <img style="width:110px;" src="images/download.jpg">                  
                </a> 

                </div>
                </div>
                </div>'; // if results are available then display to screen 
                }
            if ( $hasprintedrecords == false) // if there are no results then function below is run  
            { 
            $box .='<div id=\"video\" style=\" border-style:solid; border-color:#000000; border-width:1px;\"> <div style="border-style:dashed; border-color:#f90;" id="text"> no media found for this selection.</div></div>'; // returns html message to screen 
            }
            return $box; // returns results to the screen
        }

         public function Unverified()
        { 
           $unverified = ""; 
           $sql = "SELECT * 
                    FROM media 
                    WHERE verified = 0 "; // sql query 
           $box = "";
           $hasprintedrecords = false; // capture records if there are no records printed to screen 
           $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn); // connection to database and also getting the results from query
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) // the loop while there are results within the array run the function
            {
                $hasprintedrecords = true;// if there are records this equals true if not equals false 
                $unverified .= '

                <div style="margin-top:5px;height:120px;padding:0px;"id="Video">

                <div style="width:185px;height:105px;float:left;" id="VideoImage">
                <img style="width:185px;"class="partimg1" src="images/thumbnails/'.$row['media_id'].'.png" />
                </div>

                <div style="float:right;padding-left:5px;width:72%;font-size:12px;padding-top:0px;font:verdana,sans-serif;" id="text">
                <div style="color:#0099CC;font-weight:bold;" id="Title">'.$row['title'].'</div>
                <a style="color:#000000;text-decoration:none;padding:0px;margin:0px;font-size:12px;" href="http://www.thomasdudley.co.uk/" target="_blank">By Thomas Dudley</a> 
                <div style="font-size:13.4px;"id="Blurb">'.$row['blurb'].'</div>
                <div  id="Downloads">
                <a id="Download" href="http://thor/classroom/Downloads/'.$row['media_id'].''.$row['title'].'.exe" target="_blank">Download</a>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>'; // if results are available then display to screen 
            }

           if ( $hasprintedrecords == false) // if there are no results then function below is run  
            { 
            $unverified .='<div id=\"video\" style=\" border-style:solid; border-color:#000000; border-width:1px;\"> <div style="border-style:dashed; border-color:#f90;" id="text"> no media found for this selection.</div></div>'; // returns html message to screen 
            }
            return $unverified; // returns results to the screen
        }


            public function addNewMediaRecord($Subject, $Section, $Principle, $Title, $Blurb, $Uniq_id) { 
            $sql = "INSERT INTO media (media_id, subject_id, section_id, principle_id, title, blurb, verified, media_uniqid) 
               VALUES ('NULL', '".$Subject."', '".$Section."', '".$Principle."', '".$Title."', '".$Blurb."', '0', '".$Uniq_id."')";
            $this->addMediaCrossRef($Job, $Career, $Uniq_id); // You don't have this vars initilized in the current method?
            mysql_query($sql, $this->conn);
                    (return mysql_affected_rows($this->conn) > 0);
            }

            public function addMediaCrossRef($Job, $Career, $Uniq_id) {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO media_career_crossref (media_id, jobrole_id, career_id, verified, media_uniqid) 
            VALUES (NULL, '".$Job."', '".$Career."', '0', '".$Uniq_id."')";
            mysql_query($sql, $this->conn);
                    (return mysql_affected_rows($this->conn) > 0);
            }


        }
$opt = new SelectList();
?>
```

above is the full code that I have currently got for this web page the latest functions are the last on the page.

this is how the functions are being called from a different page

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) 
    {
        echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n"; 

        include "select.class.php";
        /*$opt->addNewMediaCrossRef($Job, $Career, $Uniq_id);*\ /* me trying to call both functions at once this didnt work either*/

        $opt->addNewRecord($Subject, $Section, $Principle, $Title, $Blurb, $Uniq_id);


        }
```

any help would be much appreciated

Comment: can you please try with mysql multiquery

Comment: This will not work with mysql_query, but you can use mysqli multiquery. However, when you are still on mysql_* you can use `mysql_query($sql1); mysql_query($sql2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answer might have stated that you can use MySQLi's multiquery option, and also as I commented you can use `*_query()` once for the first statement and second time for the second statement. However, you are braking the single responsibility principle of the method. If you want to chain to actions within one, separate them in different methods and call inwithin.

```
public function addNewMediaRecord($Subject, $Section, $Principle, $Title, $Blurb, $Uniq_id) { 
       $sql = "INSERT INTO media (media_id, subject_id, section_id, principle_id, title, blurb, verified, media_uniqid) 
               VALUES ('NULL', '".$Subject."', '".$Section."', '".$Principle."', '".$Title."', '".$Blurb."', '0', '".$Uniq_id."')";
       $this->addMediaCrossRef($Job, $Career, $Uniq_id); // You don't have this vars initilized in the current method?
       return yourQueryFunction($sql, $this->conn); 
}

public function addMediaCrossRef($Job, $Career, $Uniq_id) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO media_career_crossref (media_id, jobrole_id, career_id, verified, media_uniqid) 
         VALUES (NULL, '".$Job."', '".$Career."', '0', '".$Uniq_id."')";
    return yourQueryFunction($sql, $this->conn);
}
```

And normally methods do not return the `query()` return value, especially when they are insert/update

I would prefer:

```
public function addNewMediaRecord($all_the_params) {
    $sql = ".....";
    yourQueryFunction($sql);
    $this->chainedMethod($params);
    return yourFunctionforAFFECTED_ROWS() > 0;
}
```

So it will return boolean if affected rows are more than zero (successful insert).

---

Also you'd better wrap the database functions in order to have easier switch between libraries, when you need to.

E.g.:

```
class Database {

    private $_host;
    private $_user;
    private $_pass;
    private $_db;

    private $_conn;

    public function __construct($host, $user, $pass, $db) {
        $this->_host = $host;
        $this->_user = $user;
        $this->_pass = $pass;
        $this->_db = $db;

        $this->connect();
    }

    private function connect() {
        $this->_conn = mysqli_connect($this->_host, $this->_user, $this->_pass, $this->_db)
                or die(mysqli_error($this->_conn));
    }

    public function query($query) {
        return mysqli_query($this->_conn, $query);
    }

    public function affectedRows() {
        return mysqli_affected_rows($this->_conn);
    }
```

---

```
class TheClassWhereYourMethodsYouHaveShownAre {

    protected $_db;    

    public function __construct() {
        $this->_db = new Database('host', 'user', 'pass', 'db');
    }


    public function addNewMediaRecord($Subject, $Section, $Principle, $Title, $Blurb, $Uniq_id) { 
           $sql = "INSERT INTO media (media_id, subject_id, section_id, principle_id, title, blurb, verified, media_uniqid) 
               VALUES ('NULL', '".$Subject."', '".$Section."', '".$Principle."', '".$Title."', '".$Blurb."', '0', '".$Uniq_id."')";
           $this->addMediaCrossRef($Job, $Career, $Uniq_id); // You don't have this vars initilized in the current method?
           $this->_db->query($sql);
           return $this->_db->affectedRows > 0;
    }
```

Comment: where you have put yourQueryFunction what would go here ?? @RoyalBg

Comment: This should be depending on what you are about to switch. That.s mysql_query, mysqli_query, pdo->execute, or wrapped function, which I would prefer (a class where you have wrapped the query function): `$this->_db->query("....");` where you have i.e. `public function query($sql) { return mysqli_query($sql); }`

Comment: so if I was just going to use mysql then it would be

`return mysql_query($sql, $this->conn):` @RoyalBg

Comment: @user3387522 Check my last exmaple with the wrapper. If you are going to use mysql_query, just remove the `i` from all of the functions in the Database class (I have used to same style as mysql_

Comment: If you do not intend to use wrapper. The mysql_ style would be: `mysql_query($sql, $this->conn); return mysql_affected_rows() > 0`

Comment: I have tried `mysql_query($sql, $this->conn);` and then return `mysql_affected_rows() > 0` but this stops the page from working any ideas ??

Comment: I guess once you have tried to specify a connection, you'd need to all function, so `mysql_affected_rows($this->conn)`. But if it does not work, then before the return try `var_dump(mysql_affected_rows() or die(mysql_error));`

Comment: Ok most of the functions work on the site but the sql is not inserting anything into the database

Comment: add `or mysql_error($this->conn)` after each `mysql_query($sql, $this->conn)` in order to check what does prevent the sql from executing

Comment: nothing is being displayed to the screen but i also tried running echo $sql; within the function because usually that shows you the query and its values but it doesn't show anything either

Comment: Switch on you error reporting, you might have problem from before the function call. Can you post your current  code to your original question?

Comment: @user3387522 well, as in you original question, there was the same problem. You wanted to perform two sql queries in which you wanted to use variables that was not present in the function. E.g.: in ` addNewMediaRecord()` you dont have `$Job` variable. Also you don't actually have `mysql_query()` in both `add` methods

Comment: ok the `$vars` such as `$Job` these are posted to this page the running to queries in one function was so that I can insert results into two different tables at the exact same time. the reason mysql_query() is because you told me to use `mysql_affected_rows($this->conn);`  @RoyalBg

Comment: @user3387522 I told you to return mysql_Affected_rows after mysql_query is used :)

Comment: you said 

_I guess once you have tried to specify a connection, you'd need to all function, so mysql_affected_rows($this->conn). But if it does not work, then before the return try var_dump(mysql_affected_rows() or die(mysql_error));_  

So how should this actually be cause I am kinda confused at the moment

Comment: you need `mysql_query($sql, $this->conn)` to perform the query and then return if the affected rows are more than zero (`return mysql_affected_rows($this->conn) > 0`). Still your code will not work if the parameters passed are not present. Variables might be posted, but you now than `$Job` is not `$_POST['Job']`. Initialize them before

Comment: the $job values are being posted into this page by another so the $job has values all i need to do is put .$Job. this works and it has been tested due to the fact it was working before I changed my code

Comment: No matter how they are posted, they are not in the function scope. If you have been using register_globals, you will have hard time with the next upgrade of PHP. But, OK, let's not talk about this. Did you manage to make your script working with mysql_query and mysql_affected_rows? Saw my last examples?

Comment: Any errors you're getting? Is the SQL printed when you do "echo". Maybe mysql_error() again?

Comment: i have tried both of these options using the `var_dump(mysql_affected_rows() or die(mysql_error));` and i have tried to ocho the sql query and all i get is a blank page @RoyalBg

Comment: Where the functions are called? you have this line `$opt = new SelectList();` but you do not call any other method from the class?

Comment: the $opt is from a different page this is where the $vars get the values from

Comment: Can you post how the the `addNewMediaRecord()` function is called from this different page? Maybe some small snippet of code? Also could you try turn error reporting in all the pages `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1)`

Comment: i have tried the error reporting but nothing was posted to the screen and i have added the call function from the other page to my answer

Comment: `addNewMediaRecord` instead of `addNewRecord`

Comment: ok they are both showing on the screen now but neither are posting anything to the database @RoyalBg

Comment: none but all the values in the sql query are correct

Comment: It's no different than your code, it should execute the mysql_query statement. When you pate the echoed SQL in the mysql console, they are isnrted correctly?

Comment: It is the same and when try both sql in both tables they both work

Comment: I still guess the variables are not passed between functioms which made them stop, so I would suggest changing the order in the inner method call and mysql_query. First use mysql_query, the call $this->...

Comment: shows me white screen and no error message any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

mysql_query() sends a unique query
You can use mysqli_multi_query function but with PHP mysqli extension.

but, if you are dead set to use mysql_query then try this-

```
<?php
$str="query1;query2;"; // 

$query = explode(';',$str);

// Run the queries
foreach($query as $index => $sql)
{
   $result = mysql_query($sql);    
   // Perform an additional operations here
}
?>
```